# Fitting boxcar (rectangle) function in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a boxcar / rectangle function to a dataset in R. I am using nls and a custom function describing a unit pulse of varying width. Here is what I have so far:

```
# Defines the unit pulse function
# The left side of the pulse is at x0, the right at x1
pulse <- function(x, x0, x1) {
  if (x >= x0 & x <= x1) {
    return (1)
  } else {
    return (0)
  }
}

xdata <- 1:30
ydata <- c(sample(-1:1, 10, replace = TRUE), sample(10:15, 10, replace = TRUE), sample(-1:1, 10, replace = TRUE))

plot(xdata, ydata)

df <- data.frame(xdata, ydata)

fitfit <- nls(ydata ~ I(A * pulse(xdata, L, R) + B), df, start = list(L = 0, R = 1, B = 0, A = 10))
```

I am having trouble understanding the error I get:

> Error in qr(.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient")) : 
>     dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [30]
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In if (x >= x0 & x <= x1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   2: In if (x >= x0 & x <= x1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   3: In if (x >= x0 & x <= x1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   4: In if (x >= x0 & x <= x1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   5: In if (x >= x0 & x <= x1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   6: In if (x >= x0 & x <= x1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   7: In .swts * attr(rhs, "gradient") :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: I fixed the error but then you run into the problem that nls is unable to construct a gradient to "decide which way to go" given the starting points. I also think the +B in the formula is overparameterizing, but leaving it out does not solve the flat-gradient problem.

Comment: I wonder if the `segmented` or `strucchange` packages would be a better fit to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-smooth functions can cause problems.  Try brute force over the two boundaries of the pulse and optimization over the linear parameters.  Note that below we have added a `set.seed` to make `ydata` reproducible.

```
library(nls2)

set.seed(123)
xdata <- 1:30
ydata <- c(sample(-1:1, 10, replace = TRUE), sample(10:15, 10, replace = TRUE), 
  sample(-1:1, 10, replace = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(xdata, ydata)

pulse <- function(x, x0, x1) (x >= x0 & x <= x1) + 0
st <- subset(expand.grid(L = xdata, R = xdata), L < R)

nls2(ydata ~ cbind(pulse(xdata, L, R), 1), df, start = st, alg = "plinear-brute")
```

giving some error messages which you can ignore and finally this output where `.lin1` and `.lin2` correspond to `A` and `B` in the question:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: ydata ~ cbind(pulse(xdata, L, R), 1)
   data: df
    L     R .lin1 .lin2 
 11.0  20.0  12.4   0.2 
 residual sum-of-squares: 49.6

Number of iterations to convergence: 435 
Achieved convergence tolerance: NA
```

Answer (score 0):

your pulse function doesn't return a vector, try this one:

```
pulse <- function(x, x0, x1) {
     ifelse (x >= x0 & x <= x1,1,0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks HubertL. I tried this and it cleared up the output, except now I get this instead: Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates